# Is it possible to get refresh token from Google without running a server on my VPS?

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-cloud-messaging

I need refresh token so that I can send messages to registered Chrome browsers using GCM. However most of the [tutorials](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/real_world_example_with_refresh.html) I consulted require a server to be running at my side and I have to do everything manually, open the auth url, authenticate it and get redirected to my server to get refresh token.

I was hoping if there is a way to do this without running a server at my side. Is it possible to get refresh token just using `client id` and `client secret`?

Once I get a refresh token I have to do a POST to GCM server to send notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get refresh token just using client_id and client_secret. Only in authorization code flow, refresh token is issued. Good news is refresh token will not be expire until user revoke it, so you can use it for a long long time. So you can once get it and use it. In authorization code flow, you need a server to get redirected tokens.

Comment: so only at the first time I need server, once I acquire refresh token, can I use it in my cron scripts?